# What interactions mediate SUSY processes?

Tags: supersymmetry

What interactions mediate SUSY processes? E.g.
$$\tilde{\chi}^{\pm} \rightarrow \tilde{\chi}^{0} + W^{\pm}$$
or
$$\tilde{q} \rightarrow q + \tilde{\chi}^{0}$$
Are they the same interactions from the SM, or are SUSY processes mediated by some additional interactions introduced by SUSY?

Comment: Are you asking for the MSSM Lagrangian?

Comment: Tilde particles are not part of the SM; is this what you are asking?

Comment: Take the following decay $Z\rightarrow e^{+}e^{-}$. We say that $Z$ decays via the weak interaction. So my question is: What interaction mediates a process like: $\tilde{q}\rightarrow q+\tilde{\chi}^{0}$?